# Stuck in connecting state while connecting to socket.io with swift

Tags: swift, socket.io

I am trying to connect socket.io with swift 4. But when I try to connect socket server as their documentation says, my socket.status getting stuck in connecting state. Could anyone help me please. This is my code to connect socket.io.
https://socket-io-chat.now.sh/ is their test socket chat server.

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string:"https://socket-io-chat.now.sh/")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])

func add(){
    let socket = manager.defaultSocket

    socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
        print("socket connected")
    }

    socket.on(clientEvent: .disconnect) { (data, ack) in
        print("disconnect")
    }

    socket.on(clientEvent: .error) { (data, ack) in
        print("error connect")
    }

    socket.connect()
    for index in 1...50  {
        print("\(socket.status) +\(index)")
    }
}
```

This is how I called that class method.

```
SocketIOManager().add()
```

Comment: I believe you are missing all of the TLS negotiation callbacks, your socket cannot be fully connected until security parameters have been negotiated.  Notice the "https" in your URL.

Comment: But it keep getting stuck in connecting state even thought I test with my localhost server. @ekscrypto

Answer (score 2):

You **must store instance of `SocketManager` somewhere** (or in you case SocketIOManager, that contains SocketManager) after you created it and connected.

For example, just create variable for your `SocketIOManager` in your `ViewConroller` (or static variable)

```
var socketIOManager = SocketIOManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
   socketIOManager.add()
}


@IBAction func testButtonTap(_ sender: Any) {
    var status = socketIOManager.manager.defaultSocket.status
    print("\(status)")
}
```